# Samba Error: "Incorrect Function"

Tags: linux, windows-xp, redhat, samba

I've been setting up a samba share on a Redhat box, and am able to connect to it from the local machine.  From an XP machine however, I'm only able to successfully connect to the root of the share (e.g. "\machine").  Connecting to the actual shared folders (e.g. "\machine\share") generates an error.

The full error message is:

> \machine\share is not accessible. 
>   You might not have permission to use
>   this network resource.  Contact the
>   administrator of this server to find
>   out if you have access permissions.
>
> Incorrect function.

Looking at the properties on the windows side, I see "everyone", "root (Unix Group\root)", and "root (Unix User\root") listed with no permissions.

I'm using share authentication, and the user I've designated for the guest account has read/write access to the shared folder.

Has anyone run into a similar issue before?  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the windows machine was caching authentication information, and not updating it as the samba server's authentication mode was changed.  This meant that once I'd failed to connect to the samba server (due to bad settings on the server side), connections would continue to fail even when the server settings were corrected.  Rebooting the XP machine resolved the issue.